# build or construct in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

> We built a bridge.
>
> We construct a bridge.

Are there any difference between "bulid "and "construct" in this sentence?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Discussions about the definitions of words are off-topic for us but may be acceptable on English if correctly phrased. I'll ask the mods if this can be migrated.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - Migrated.